# UpdateProgress won't show when causing an UpdatePanel to refresh with javascript

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel and inside the update panel I have a button. The updatepanel also has an updateprogress control tied to it in order to display a loading graphic when the updatepanel does a postback.

If I click the button in the update panel then the progress loader shows up just fine. However, if I select the button with jQuery and do `.click()` the loader doesn't show up. The panel does post back and load content correctly but the progress loader doesn't trigger.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find the answer to this question but it doesn't matter. I learned that update panels only make one request at a time for a reason. The page life-cycle and viewstate cannot be broken, therefore asynchronous requests can only be made one at a time.

MVC for the win.

Answer (score 1):

I just have tried your scenario. It works fine here.

Here is the html

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <img src="Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <input id="btnTest" title="JQuery Click" onclick="ClickButton1()" type="button"  value="JQuery Click" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ClickButton1() {     
      //  alert('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>');
        $('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').click();
        }
    </script>
```

Here is the back end code to show loading image for 5 seconds

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Also, isn't UpdateProgress normally place outside of the UpdatePanel? (I tried both and neither worked for me; the UpdatePanel worked but not the UpdateProgress :( ).